# Pass to Widget a Function that returns a future

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass to my Widget a function that returns a future:

```
class CircularButtonWithIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  CircularButtonWithIcon(
      {Key key,
      @required this.onPress,
      this.activeStatus})
      : super(key: key);
  final Function activeStatus;

class _CircularButtonWithIconState extends State<CircularButtonWithIcon> {
  bool active;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.activeStatus.then(...);
  }
```

However Dart's class `Function` has no way to specify that the function's return type.

Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the return type front of the `Function`

i.e.

```
class CircularButtonWithIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  Future<void> Function() activeStatus;
  CircularButtonWithIcon({Key key, @required this.onPress, this.activeStatus,}) : super(key: key);
}
```